# Socket.io client not connecting

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I have a Socket.io server running on port 3000 and when running it (and the website / client) locally everything works fine. But when I push it to the server the client can't connect anymore.

The production server is running over SSL so I assumed that I need the Socket.io server to run over SSL as well. I've setup it up like this:

```
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');

var is_production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

if(is_production){
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/cert.pem'),
        requestCert: true
    };

    var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
}else{
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
}

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

This still doesn't work. I don't have much experience with Socket.io so any help would be appreciated. Also note that everything worked fine before I got an SSL certificate setup on the web server.

The client is connecting to `ws://mywebsite.com:3000`. I've tried using `http://`, `https://` and `wss://` as well, but nothing works.

**EDIT:** I've tried making a request through `curl` and I get the following error:

```
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what the problem was, so here's what I did.

I have Nginx running on the same server to serve my website so what I ended up doing was configuring Nginx to proxy all SSL connections to port `3000` and forward them to the node.js server running on port `8080`. This way Nginx takes care of the SSL so the node.js server doesn't need any additional configuration.